# Continuous Representation vs Distributed representation

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language

I read [this](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2841&context=compsci) paper and *Hinton* categorized data representation into:

- Localist (local) representation
- Distributed representation

In another [presentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiygfrdpfLSAhWF54MKHesqBlMQFggnMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.derczynski.com%2Fsheffield%2Fteaching%2Finno%2F9a.pptx&usg=AFQjCNG7f6OvHBI0nxrHXsn2P0wLmbjrCA&sig2=7r9XrToE_cA76scpPTWM3w&bvm=bv.150729734,d.amc) by *Mikolov* categorized text into:

- Local representation

  - N-grams
  - One hot vector
  - Bag of words
- Continuous representation

  - Distributed representation
  - LSI (LSA)
  - LDA

I want to know which one is correct? 
Any reference for that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer of Tomas Mikolov to my question:

> I believe both are correct - where do you see the disagreement? LDA /
>   LSA are not exactly distributed representations IMHO, but they are
>   examples of continuous representations (in contrast to the discrete
>   ones).